# run a cloned repository for django project

Tags: django, importerror, manage.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cand/Python_Project/Data Science Github/gitando/django-simples/manage.py", line 10, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cand/Python_Project/Data Science Github/gitando/django-simples/manage.py", line 21, in 
main()
File "/home/cand/Python_Project/Data Science Github/gitando/django-simples/manage.py", line 12, in main
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Comment: You need to install django and other dependencies for the project. The best way to do this is to use a virtual environment in order to keep the project's dependencies separate from any other projects you might want to run on your machine.

Comment: I used this sequence:

git clone https://github.com/rg3915/django-simples.git;
cd django-simples;
python3 -m venv .venv;
source .venv/bin/activate;
pip3 install -r requirements.txt;
python contrib/env_gen.py;
python manage.py migrate

Comment: That looks like all the correct commands.

Comment: I'm trying to duplicate on Windows using WSL2. I git some errors when I run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`. I'm checking if you got any errors, too? Other than that I was still able to continue and run `manage.py migrate`. The error you are asking about makes me believe that you didn't have the virtual environment activated when you ruan the command. Double check that.

Comment: p.s. You should [edit] your quesiton to include the commands. Also, I recommend that you work through [the official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/) to learn Django. This will help you understand the concepts better than a random project on GitHub.

Comment: yes for this project i'm having errors, actually my biggest goal is to understand how i can run a django project cloned in github

Comment: The projects I create on my computer don't have a problem, the biggest difficulty is with the projects cloned on github.

Comment: Yes, running someone else's project almost always has difficulties. Hopefully my answer below solves the immediate error you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `source .venv/bin/activate` before running any other python commands. This should solve the error you are asking about. I recommend that you read more about virtual environments with Python to understand better how to use them.